# building flexible and reusable class hierarchy

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Let's review some entities:

- **Company**;
- **Collaborator**;
- **Chief**;
- **Subordinate workers**.

There are some rules:

1. **Collaborator** could be one of these: *Sales*, *Manager*,
   *Employee*;
2. Sales and Manager could have subordinate workers (of any type decribed in the 1st rule);
3. Sales, Manager, Employee could have chief;
4. Each role has its own Salary
   calculation method.

So the target is to create flexible & reusable class hierarchy.

---

First thing that confuses me is "can have" phrase. Should it be implemented as a composition? If it is said "can have as many" should it be a composition with list of objects?

Should I create abstract class Collaborator and then inherit from it 3 other types or there is more smart way?

What is the best way to tie all the entities together and have good reusable assembly?

Comment: What are the rules for salary calculation? Every role has a different one, or some have shared salary calculation?

Comment: I would also ask for clarification on `Subordinate workers` and `Employees` to get a better idea of the relationship.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris every role has its own salary calculation, but the Collaborator class keeps shared baseSalary.

Answer (score 0):

`"Can have"` and the fact that its followed by `"workers"`, tells me this is a `"has a"` relationship (composition) with a 0 to many relationship (so a list as you mention that could be empty)

An abstract class Collaborator seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Can have is represented in UML as (0..*) which means either 0 or more, yes composition with a list of objects would be good, use collections not an array.

Collaborator is an Abstract class since there will be no instances of Collaborator itself. Inheriting the 3 types of Collaborator is the best way I guess.

I have to add that, if you only have one company in your project, you need to implement the `Singleton` design pattern.

About the Salary use virtual method and override it.

I hope this is not your homework ;)

Comment: You can just write `*` instead of `0..*` for simplicity.

Comment: No, it isn't my homework) I've been asked about it and considering assembly reusability as the target .. this question seems to be not so trivial. Since there are lots of books about Business objects. I just can't imagine the kind of abstraction to use roles.

Comment: No need for Singleton at all.

Comment: @H.B I know (both are used usually), @helicera I hope you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this question is subjective and would change depending on your needs but this is how I would implement it:

```
public class Company {
    public List<Collaborator> Collaborators { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Collaborator {
    public Collaborator(Company company) {
        company.Collaborators.Add(this);
    }
    public virtual Decimal Salary(object value);
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Sales : Collaborator {
    public override Decimal Salary(object value) {}
    public List<Collaborator> Subordinates { get; set; }
    public Collaborator Chief { get; set }
}

public class Manager : Collaborator {
    public override Decimal Salary(object value) {}
    public List<Collaborator> Subordinates { get; set; }
    public Collaborator Chief { get; set }
}

public class Employee : Collaborator {
    public override Decimal Salary(object value) {}
    public Collaborator Chief { get; set }
}
```

*This code has not been tested.*

Comment: But how do I connect it to company entity?

Comment: You didn't describe the connection to company. It could be just a list of Collaborator's if you only need functionality from the Collaborator class.

Answer (score 0):

I find the question poorly formulated, the design can change severly by just adding small extra information.

Based on what you wrote, I might consider creating the following classes ('-' means extends):

```
Company

AbstractCollaborator (Chief member, CalculateSalary() { return base + AdditionalSalary() }, abstract AdditionalSalary())
- Chief
- AbstractLeader ( List subordinates )
-- Sales
-- Manager
- Employee
```

Chief would have no chief set for itself. I would try to prevent using virtual functions, and try using abstract functions instead.

Another option would be to simply using one class. It's all nice and well that only Sales or Manager can have subordinates, but in a real world situation it might be necessary for anyone to have subordinates. The function of any type of employee could simply be specified by a enum value instead.

It all depends greatly at where you are going with this ...

Comment: @helicera: Updated to support base salary.